# Converting or casting DataTable types

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a number of classes that look like, for example

```
public class VarcharTokens : DataTable
{
  public VarcharTokens()
  {
    Columns.Add("Value", typeof(string));
  }
}
```

What I want to be able to do is read from one database and write to another, passing a `DataTable` between the two.  If the source returns a `DataTable` and the destination expects a `VarcharTokens` then I need a highly efficient method to cast, convert or otherwise handle the difference in types.

I suppose `DataTable` extension methods would work, somehow.  I tried looking at explicit/implicit operators but `user-defined conversions to or from a base type are not allowed`.

What are my options?

If at all possible I would like not to end up with 2 copies of the data; the quantities of data are truly colossal in my use-case.

Comment: [`DataTable.Merge` ?](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Epmalb)

Comment: @Selvin so, create a new table of target type and merge the source into the dest?

Comment: I think it is outrageous that someone has voted to close this question after just one suggestion and within just a few minutes of it being asked.

Comment: I suppose what I am hoping for is some method to assign rather than copy the data

Comment: Simply you can't as VarcharTokens is DataTable but obviously DataTable is not VarcharTokens

Comment: @Selvin - sorted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I came up with was an extension method as follows

```
        public static VarcharTokens ToVarcharTokens(this DataTable dt)
        {
            var result = new VarcharTokens();

            dt.AsEnumerable().All(r => { result.Rows.Add().ItemArray = r.ItemArray; return true; });
```

which I subsequently generalised like this

```
    public static T DTConvert<T>(this DataTable dt) where T:DataTable, new ()
    {
        try
        {
            T result = new T();

            dt.AsEnumerable().All(r => { result.Rows.Add().ItemArray = r.ItemArray; return true; });

            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception($"UDTConversionError to {typeof(T)} : {ex.Message}"); 
        }
    }
```